When a non-linear dynamical system is put under stress, is the tendency towards infinite attractors a phase transition?
An attractor is a region of the state space which, when a system enters that state, keeps the system from evolving out of it.
Given certain parameters, such as energy, a system will settle into a set of attractors.
Once settled, a parameter can be changed. For example, flow or energy. With increased energy we can disturb the system out of its settled state. This can result in an increase in the number of attractors present in the system.
At a critical threshold, the number of attractors tends to infinity.
My question is that this seems pretty similar to the description of a phase transition in statistical mechanics. Is it the same process described by different regimes?
Further, does this imply that the infinite attractors of one system's "pure chaos" can give rise to a higher level, emergent, set of attractors to be regarded as those of a new system. E.g. the attractors of a liquid versus the attractors of its gas phase.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
